# How to summon a ravager with momentum

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to summon a ravager with a certain momentum on a command block?

I did summon minecraft:ravager but I don't know how to give it momentum.

Comment: Please state which direction do you want it to go to, and where it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Motion tag:

```
summon minecraft:ravanger ~ ~2 ~ {Motion:[1.0,1.0,0.0]}
```

This will summon a Ravager moving up and towards positive X